# How to Change "About Me" URL in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, sharepoint-on-prem, mysite, sharepoint-server

I need to Change "About Me" URL in SharePoint 2016 to be "https" instead of "http".
Note that "My Site" is in the same Web application with other sites.

Comment: Does your web application support HTTPS? Are you using AAM?

Comment: Yes, it supports HTTPS. It works when I use HTTPS not HTTP that's why I want to change "About Me" URL to go to the correct URL.

Comment: It has been a while since I configured the UPS on-prem. But it shold return the correct URL depending on which AAM Zone you are in. Are you referencing the URL from a HTTPS Zone?